# Как создать повтор для вызова метода класса Python

Tags: python, классы, методы

В коде ниже есть класс `Dice()`, который задает обычный шестигранный кубик, в нем метод `roll_dice()`, выбрасывающий случайное число от 1 до 6. У меня было задание вызвать `roll_dice()` 10 раз. Вопрос: как можно сократить этот код, чтобы не нужно было целых 10 строчек одно и то же писать (и если понадобится изменить кол-во бросков, не пришлось это всё каждый раз удалять/добавлять)? Может можно как-то с помощью цикла это провернуть, а результаты бросков в список заносить? Может еще один метод создать нужно?

```py
from random import randint

class Dice():
    def __init__(self):
        self.sides = 6

    def roll_dice(self):
        number = randint(1, self.sides)
        print(number)

print('Первый кубик:')
dice1 = Dice()

dice1.roll_dice()
dice1.roll_dice()
dice1.roll_dice()
dice1.roll_dice()
dice1.roll_dice()
dice1.roll_dice()
dice1.roll_dice()
dice1.roll_dice()
dice1.roll_dice()
dice1.roll_dice()
```

Comment: Зачем вам ещё метод? Идея ООП - отражение реальности. Соотвественно, метод - один бросок кубика в общем случае. Да, все верно - "с помощью цикла это провернуть, а результаты бросков в список заносить?" Просто допишите код.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример для десяти бросков

```py
from random import randint

class Dice():
    def __init__(self):
        self.sides = 6
    def roll_dice(self):
        number = randint(1, self.sides)
        # print(number)
        return number


print('Первый кубик:')
dice1 = Dice()

for i in range(10):
    print(f"Бросок номер {i+1}, выпало {dice1.roll_dice()}")
```

в функции `print()` убрал, не хорошо это)

Вывод

```
Бросок номер 1, выпало 4
Бросок номер 2, выпало 1
Бросок номер 3, выпало 1
Бросок номер 4, выпало 2
Бросок номер 5, выпало 6
Бросок номер 6, выпало 5
Бросок номер 7, выпало 4
Бросок номер 8, выпало 3
Бросок номер 9, выпало 6
Бросок номер 10, выпало 4
```

Comment: спасибо, меня это натолкнуло на мысль, как надо сделать. А можно поподробнее, почему в функции нужно return лучше использовать, а не print?

Comment: @Jur Есть такое понятие "чистая функция". Одно из положений гласит: _функция не использует стандартного ввода/вывода._ Подразумевается `print(), input()`. Все что нужно в функции передавайте аргументами, результат возвращайте `return`. Методы класса могут модифицировать поля, например, но это не тот случай

Comment: Понятно, спасибо